# InterlockedAdd64 can't be found after adding _AFXDLL macro and clr support

Tags: c++, mfc, clr, afx

I added _AFXDLL macro and got the following two errors:

```
error C2039: 'InterlockedAdd64': is not a member of '`global namespace''
error C3861: 'InterlockedAdd64': identifier not found
```

What is the reason and how to work around the issue?

I ran into the issue while trying to add c++/clr support for DLL which uses MFC.

Comment: from the documentation, you might want to try this instead: This function is implemented using a compiler intrinsic where possible. For more information, see the Winbase.h header file and _InterlockedAdd64.

Comment: Related: [InterlockedIncrement64 with managed C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549166/interlockedincrement64-with-managed-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I'm out of luck if I want to use clr support:

> [MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros) _MANAGED Defined as 1 when the /clr compiler option is set. Otherwise, undefined.

From winnt.h:

```
#if !defined(_MANAGED)

#if (_MSC_VER >= 1600)

...

FORCEINLINE
LONG64
_InterlockedAdd64 (
    _Inout_ _Interlocked_operand_ LONG64 volatile *Addend,
    _In_ LONG64 Value
    )
{
...
}

#define InterlockedAdd64 _InterlockedAdd64
...

#endif // !defined(_MANAGED)
```